# Can't provision any compute instance in GCP nor increase NCPU quota

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Since many days I can't provision any compute engine instance in my google cloud business account.

Billing is enabled on the project, I can't tell what's wrong from my side.

I sent a first request to the support before yesterday, yesterday, and today again, and here is a screenshot of their answer.

I'm lost, I don't understand why they ask to check with their sales team.[image]

Here my terraform output error :

> google_compute_instance.lykanda-backend: Creating...
>   google_compute_instance.lykanda-backend: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
>   Error: Error waiting for instance to create: Quota 'N2_CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region europe-west3.
>   on compute.tf line 88, in resource "google_compute_instance" "lykanda-backend":
>   88: resource "google_compute_instance" "lykanda-backend" {

My compute instance block code :

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "lykanda-backend" {
 project = "869410787656"
 zone     = "europe-west3-a"
 name     = "lykanda-backend"
 machine_type = "n2-standard-2"
 boot_disk {
  initialize_params {
   image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
  }
 }
 network_interface {
  network = google_compute_network.lykanda.self_link
  subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.lykanda-network.self_link
  access_config {
   nat_ip = google_compute_address.lykanda-static-ip-address.address
  }
 }
 # metadata = {
 #  ssh-keys = join("\n", [for user, key in var.ssh_keys : "${user}:${key}"])
 # }
 service_account {
  scopes = ["userinfo-email", "compute-ro", "storage-ro"]
 }
 allow_stopping_for_update = true
}
```

Comment: Have you already contacted sales as suggested?

Comment: Yes I did, but just filled a form and got an acknowledgement saying that they will be in touch with me shortly

Answer (score 2):

This issue related only to your GCP quotas and it's not connected to your deployment:

> Error: Error waiting for instance to create: Quota 'N2_CPUS' exceeded. 
>   Limit: 0.0 in region europe-west3

Actually, Stack Overflow community can do nothing with such issues.

Have a look at the email from Google Cloud Support again:

> ... we are enable to proceed with your request, for this resource was
>   quite high and need capacity planning planning with our sales team. We
>   recommend you to contact sales team for capacity planning ...

and

> ... note that COMMITTED_N2_CPUS COMMITTED_N2_CPUS is for discount and real
>   quota N2_CPUS without committed words ...

As you can see, because N2 CPUs are on high demand, they aren't available. In addition, please check the documentation [Resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) and [Committed use discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts) to find more information about quotas and discounts.

**To solve this issue** you can follow steps below:

1. Contact [sales team](https://cloud.google.com/contact), as it was suggested by Google Cloud Support, and ask for increase of quota N2_CPUS.
2. Try to request increase of quota N2_CPUS for other [region/zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) where N2 machine types [available](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#available).

Answer (score 0):

I never received the sales team answer, then I dug into compute info within my project and per region to see different quota limits from command line :

```
gcloud compute project-info describe --project myproject

gcloud compute regions describe [REGION]
```

and then saw I could use `n1-standard-2` instance type which seems to be available for all region.

I tried it and it worked, so I'll continue my work this way.